# Probably a false statement

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Let n ≥ 3. Prove that a graph G on n vertices is a tree if and only if
it is not isomorphic to $K_n$ and adding any edge (on the same vertex
set) not present in G creates exactly one cycle.

I think this is a false statement, but it's in a highly reputable book so idk. Help me out. Could someone explain the proof if $G$ is not isomorphic to $K_n$ and adding any edge (on the same vertex
set) not present in G creates exactly one cycle, it is a Tree?

$K_n$ is a complete graph of n vertices.

Thank you in advance

## edited

Comment: "*and adding any edge (on the same vertex set) not present in G creates exactly one cycle*" is part of the condition. It's not only "it's not isomorphic to $K_n$".

Comment: Can you define $K_n$, please.

Comment: Done! @Crostul Could you explain the proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tree has any two vertices connected by exactly one path.  When you add an edge you turn that path into a circle.  If a graph is not a tree, either there is a pair of unconnected vertices and you can join them without forming a cycle or there is already a cycle and joining any two vertices creates at least two more cycles.

I believe you are talking about simple graphs.  The restriction on $K_n$ is just because you can't add any edges to it.

Comment: I understand what the book tried to say now. Thanks. I was confused about the intention behind K_n